Running total count, excluding inactive students by date
I'm trying to generate a running count of total students by month and year. I can easily get the total count for the year, as that's a simple COUNT(*) WHERE YEAR([DateEntered]) = 2024 type query. The problem I'm running into is that I need this broken down by month, accounting for when students became inactive. I need to know the total number of students for any given month, where that total count is the sum of all active students up to and including that month, excluding any students that quit in that month or earlier.
Here is a sample of the data:



Id
SchoolId
DateEntered
Active
DateInactive




3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA4
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA5
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


B631EDCD-A43E-420B-8462-C5C9D1935B90
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-08-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2023-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


A9710DB1-653E-4EBD-9EDE-0A8000E5D72D
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-08-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2023-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA2
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-12-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA3
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023-12-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA0
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-05-10 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA8
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-06-22 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA9
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-06-22 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL


86EF99D2-2878-4DF9-A4B5-259B470AEA3D
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-08-10 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-09-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA1
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-09-07 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFB0
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-09-21 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA7
3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024-09-21 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
NULL



So, given the sample data, I need a result that looks like this:



SchoolId
Year
Month
Total Count
Total New
Total Quit
Net Gain




3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
07
0
3
0
3


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
08
3
2
0
2


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
09
5
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
10
5
0
2
-2


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
11
3
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2023
12
3
2
0
2


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
01
5
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
02
5
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
03
5
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
04
5
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
05
5
1
0
1


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
06
6
2
0
2


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
07
8
0
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
08
8
1
0
0


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
09
9
3
1
2


3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6
2024
10
11
0
2
-2



Total new is the count of new records with a DateEntered value of the given month/year. Total quit is the count of records with a DateInactive value of that same given month/year. The net gain is total new - total quit.
The total count for a month is based on the previous month, so it's the previous month's total + the net gain of the previous month. In effect, this is the total number of students at the start of the month. That number + the net gain of the current month is the total number of students at the end of the period. That's the value all of the current answers are calculating.
I need this to calculate an attrition rate, which is (students lost during a period / total students at the beginning of the period). So, for example, if there were 9 students at the start of September 2024 and 1 quit, the attrition is (1/9) = 0.111111 (or 11%).
Conversely, if I wanted to calculate the retention rate, I need to know the total students at the start of the period and also the total at the end of the period. The calculation is (total students at the end of the period - new students during the period) / total students at the start of the period. Using the same example as above, the retention rate would be (11 - 3)/9 = 0.888889 (or 89%). In theory, the attrition rate can also be 1 - retention, which in this example would be 1 - 0.888889 = 0.111111 (or 11%), but I'd rather calculate both independently.
Ideally, I want this to come from a single query. I can get some of the data, but not all of it. I feel this should be possible with some creative use of count or sum over some partitions, but I'm unable to figure out what that should be.

I assume (hope) you have a calendar table?

This looks very similar to a question we had last week. Ah. found it. I know those SchoolIDs were familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79123384/generate-financial-summary-report

A calendar table? No, this data doesn't involve a calendar table. It's strictly based on the data in the students' table (the sample data included in the question). Ultimately, this data serves as the source for various statistics shown on a dashboard to provide "health" data about how well the school is doing.

"A calendar table? No, this data doesn't involve a calendar table." but the solution does involve one.

@BartMcEndree are you're referring to the question I asked last week, or a different question?

@ThomA How so? It's strictly based on dates in the table, and can span any range of dates based on when a school first opens.

But it's not strictly based on the dates in the table, @ScottDorman . There are no rows in your table for January 2024, for example, so that row can't exist without something. That something is the calendar table.

Aside: By COUNT(*) WHERE YEAR([DateEntered]) = 2024 you meant Count( 42 ) where '2024-01-01' <= DateEntered and DateEntered < '2025-01-01' so that the index on DateEntered can be used for an index seek.

@ThomA There isn't a row for January 2024, for example, because there was no student activity for that month (no new students added or students lost).

@ScottDorman : If you work with dates a lot, then having a dates/calendar table will make querying your data much easier in general. For instance, the 5th student in your data was active in September 2023 but as there is no row for this in your sample data it more difficult to work that out. If you join to a calendar table where the dates are between the start and end date, then you can easily see that they were present in September, or count the actual days active, or the number of Fridays, they were there etc... Maybe not required in this case, but typically very useful.

@AlanSchofield Your examples effectively sound like tracking attendance, which is handled by a separate table. Ultimately, I need to know the total number of students for the month, the number of students active (how many attended at least one class that month), inactive (total for the month - total attending), total new, total quit, and net gain. This table (the students table) is strictly the record of students joining and quitting for a given school.

Which, as several people have pointed out, including one answer, is easier done with a simple calendar table. It would take you 30 mins to find some code to create one as a one off, I'm not really sure what the resistance is?

@AlanSchofield Not opposed to a calendar table at all.

@ScottDorman - Are you familiar with upvoting or accepting answers? If none of the answers suit your needs, perhaps you can clarify in a comment of update to your question.

A calendar table will massively simplify this. I assume you have one (if you don't, go and create one). Then you can create a dataset of your months and schools (ideally from your schools table, rather than the DISTINCT I use here) and LEFT JOIN to your table. Then you can simply use conditional aggregation to get the results you want:
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Id uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY,
                            SchoolId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                            DateEntered datetimeoffset(7) NOT NULL,
                            Active bit NOT NULL,
                            DateInactive datetimeoffset(7) NULL);
GO
--Insert sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Id,
                           SchoolId,
                           DateEntered,
                           Active,
                           DateInactive)
VALUES
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA4','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-07-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA5','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-07-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-07-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('B631EDCD-A43E-420B-8462-C5C9D1935B90','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-08-13T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','0','2023-10-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00'),
('A9710DB1-653E-4EBD-9EDE-0A8000E5D72D','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-08-13T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','0','2023-10-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00'),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA2','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-12-09T00:00:00.0000000-05:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA3','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2023-12-09T00:00:00.0000000-05:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA0','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-05-10T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA8','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-06-22T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA9','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-06-22T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL),
('86EF99D2-2878-4DF9-A4B5-259B470AEA3D','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-08-10T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','0','2024-09-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00'),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA1','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-09-07T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','0','2024-10-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00'),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFB0','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-09-21T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','0','2024-10-14T00:00:00.0000000-04:00'),
('3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA7','3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6','2024-09-21T00:00:00.0000000-04:00','1',NULL);
GO
--Solution
--Get date ranges (one row per month)
WITH Dates AS(
    SELECT C.CalendarYear,
           C.CalendarMonth,
           C.CalendarDate AS StartDate,
           DATEADD(MONTH, 1, C.CalendarDate) AS EndDate
    FROM tbl.Calendar C
    WHERE C.CalendarDay = 1
      AND C.CalendarDate >= '20230701'
      AND C.CalendarDate < SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()),
--Get schools
Schools AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT SchoolID
    FROM dbo.YourTable) --hopefully you have a schools table, so don't need a DISTINCT
--Create final result set
SELECT S.SchoolId,
       D.CalendarYear,
       D.CalendarMonth,
       COUNT(YT.Id) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.DateEntered >= D.StartDate AND YT.DateEntered < D.EndDate THEN 1 END) AS New,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.DateInactive >= D.StartDate AND YT.DateInactive < D.EndDate THEN 1 END) AS Quit,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.DateEntered >= D.StartDate AND YT.DateEntered < D.EndDate THEN 1 END) -
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YT.DateInactive >= D.StartDate AND YT.DateInactive < D.EndDate THEN 1 END) AS NetGain
FROM Dates D
     CROSS JOIN Schools S
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON S.SchoolId = YT.SchoolId
                               AND D.EndDate > YT.DateEntered
                               AND (D.StartDate < YT.DateInactive OR YT.DateInactive IS NULL)
GROUP BY S.SchoolId,
         D.CalendarYear,
         D.CalendarMonth
ORDEr BY S.SchoolId,
         D.CalendarYear,
         D.CalendarMonth;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;

If this is for one school (so a parametrised query), then you don't need the CROSS JOIN to said Schools; I've assumed this would need to be expanded though (as otherwise why expose the SchoolId?).

Yes, there is a separate table with school information. What do you mean by a calendar table? Are you saying a table that has the school ID and what dates? Start and end date? That would be the date the school first started and the current date. The start date, in that context, is going to be different for each school ID.

@ScottDorman -  The calendar table is simply "all" dates.   It allows you to report on dates that aren't present in your data.  It will also typically give you other useful attributes (year, month, day of week, etc),  There's tons of info out there on them.

@thom-a - I added a calendar table, and combining your answer with bits of the other answers got me 99% of the way. However, my original math was wrong for the total count. It should be the previous month's total plus the previous month's net gain. I don't see how to get that value, though

The expected results in your qusetion don't appear to have changed though, @ScottDorman , should it be updated?

@ThomA Yes, the total column changed. Effectively, all of the totals were offset by one month. For example, for 10/2024, the total should be 11 not 9.

You may wish to group your data first and left join it to target set of 'cells' of schoolId+Year+Month then.
with grp as(
  select SchoolId, y, m, 
    --sum(sum(events.ent - events.inact)) over (partition by SchoolId order by y,m) total,
    sum(events.new - events.out) gain,
    sum(events.new) new, 
    sum(events.out) out
  from YourTable 
  cross apply (
    select Year(DateEntered) y, Month(DateEntered) m, 1 new, 0 out
    union all
    select Year(DateInactive) y, Month(DateInactive ), 0, 1
    where DateInactive is not null
  ) events
  group by SchoolId, y, m
), cym as (
  -- quick tally calendar for the required interval of year, month
  select y,m
  from (values (2023),(2024)) t1(y)
  cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) t2(m)
  where y*100 + m between 202307 and 202411
)
select  s.Id SchoolId, cym.y Year, cym.m Month,
  coalesce(sum(grp.gain) over(partition by s.Id order by cym.y, cym.m rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0) Total,
  coalesce(grp.gain, 0) Gain,
  coalesce(grp.new, 0) New,
  coalesce(grp.out, 0) Out
from cym
cross join schools s
left join grp on cym.y=grp.y and cym.m=grp.m and s.Id=grp.SchoolId
order by s.Id, cym.y, cym.m;

EDIT
Following your comment the target 'cells' definition is altered to account for a specific start date for a school.
..
), cym as (
  -- quick tally calendar 
  select y,m
  from (values (2023),(2024)) t1(y)
  cross join (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) t2(m)
)
select  s.Id SchoolId, cym.y Year, cym.m Month,
  coalesce(sum(grp.gain) over(partition by s.Id order by cym.y, cym.m rows between unbounded preceding and current row), 0) Total,
  coalesce(grp.gain, 0) Gain,
  coalesce(grp.new, 0) New,
  coalesce(grp.out, 0) Out
-- target 'cells'
from cym
join schools s on y*100 + m between Year(s.DateStart)*100 + Month(s.DateStart) and Year(current_timestamp)*100 + Month(current_timestamp)
--
left join grp on cym.y=grp.y and cym.m=grp.m and s.Id=grp.SchoolId
order by s.Id, cym.y, cym.m
;

db<>fiddle

This approach gets me everything I need but assumes the start/end dates are known (2023-07 and 2024-11). The end date is known, as it will always be the current month/year, but the start date is unknown and will differ for each school.

@ScottDorman,  What is the rule to calculate the start date depending on a school? I can imagine it being a column in the Schools table or calculated on the fly as min(DateEntered) for a school.

Yes, it would be a column in the schools table.

@ScottDorman , see the edit

The first part is the UNION of counters of all events by month. Here the event is the Entered or Inactived of the student. It was possible to connect (union all) rows and then group, you can group events by month and then UNION ALL.
I preferred pre-grouping because it is easier and better to cover it with indexes. The result of the grouping is already small, and you can sort and group it  inexpensively.
Second part is aggregating counters (count(*) Entered and count(*) Inactaved) by month and then, calculate running total and Net_Gain.
For month in interval between first and last month, where no events are,
we add rows by recursive part of query.
The recursion here is small, since there should not be so many empty rows that need to be filled in. Also, recursion does not require outer JOIN here.
If these empty months are not needed, the recursive part of the query can be deleted.
See example
with agg as(
select SchoolId,datepart(year,DateEntered) yy,datepart(month,DateEntered) mm
  ,count(*) Entered
  ,0 Inactived
from test
group by SchoolId,datepart(year,DateEntered),datepart(month,DateEntered)
union all
select SchoolId,datepart(year,DateInactive) yy,datepart(month,DateInactive) mm
  ,0 Entered
  ,sum(case when DateInactive is not null then 1 else 0 end) Inactived
from test
where DateInactive is not null
group by SchoolId,datepart(year,DateInactive),datepart(month,DateInactive)
)
,rep as(
select SchoolId,yy,mm
  ,coalesce(sum(sum(Entered))over(partition by SchoolId order by yy,mm),0)
   -coalesce(sum(sum(Inactived))over(partition by SchoolId order by yy,mm),0) Total_Count
  ,coalesce(sum(Entered),0) Total_new
  ,coalesce(sum(Inactived),0) Total_Quit
  ,coalesce(sum(Entered),0)-coalesce(sum(Inactived),0) as Net_Gain
  ,lead(yy,1,yy)over(partition by SchoolId order by yy,mm) next_yy
  ,lead(mm,1,mm)over(partition by SchoolId order by yy,mm) next_mm
from agg
group by SchoolId,yy,mm
  
  union all
select SchoolId
   ,case when (r.mm+1)>12 then r.yy+1 else yy end yy
   ,case when (r.mm+1)>12 then 1 else r.mm+1 end mm
   ,r.Total_count, 0 as Total_new,0 as Total_quit, 0 as Net_Gain
   ,next_yy,next_mm
from rep r
  where (yy+1)<=next_yy 
    or (yy=next_yy and (r.mm+1)<next_mm)
)
select  SchoolId, yy, mm, Total_Count, Total_new, Total_Quit, Net_Gain
from rep
order by SchoolId,yy,mm






SchoolId
yy
mm
Total_Count
Total_new
Total_Quit
Net_Gain




3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
7
3
3
0
3


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
8
5
2
0
2


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
9
5
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
10
3
0
2
-2


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
11
3
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2023
12
5
2
0
2


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
1
5
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
2
5
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
3
5
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
4
5
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
5
6
1
0
1


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
6
8
2
0
2


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
7
8
0
0
0


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
8
9
1
0
1


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
9
11
3
1
2


3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
2024
10
9
0
2
-2



fiddle

@TN, thank you. Corrected.

I'd suggest the following steps:

Identify the start date for each school based on the earliest DateEntered.
Iterate month by month dynamically from this start date until the end date (current month and year).
Compute the total count of active users, new entries, quits, and net gain month by month, without assuming a fixed start date.

WITH DateRanges AS (
    -- Get the earliest and latest dates per school to set the date range
    SELECT 
        SchoolId,
        MIN(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DateEntered), MONTH(DateEntered), 1)) AS StartDate,
        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AS EndDate
    FROM [YourTableName]
    GROUP BY SchoolId
),
MonthlyData AS (
    -- Generate monthly statistics for new entries and inactivations
    SELECT 
        SchoolId,
        DATEPART(YEAR, DateEntered) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH, DateEntered) AS Month,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalNew,
        0 AS TotalQuit
    FROM [YourTableName]
    GROUP BY SchoolId, DATEPART(YEAR, DateEntered), DATEPART(MONTH, DateEntered)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        SchoolId,
        DATEPART(YEAR, DateInactive) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH, DateInactive) AS Month,
        0 AS TotalNew,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalQuit
    FROM [YourTableName]
    WHERE DateInactive IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY SchoolId, DATEPART(YEAR, DateInactive), DATEPART(MONTH, DateInactive)
),
AllMonths AS (
    -- Generate a sequence of months from each school’s start to end date
    SELECT 
        dr.SchoolId,
        DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, dr.StartDate) AS MonthDate,
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, dr.StartDate)) AS Year,
        DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, dr.StartDate)) AS Month
    FROM DateRanges dr
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS Number
        FROM master..spt_values -- a table with enough rows for the month range
    ) n
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, n.Number, dr.StartDate) <= dr.EndDate
),
MonthlyAggregates AS (
    -- Aggregate monthly data by joining to all generated months
    SELECT 
        am.SchoolId,
        am.Year,
        am.Month,
        ISNULL(md.TotalNew, 0) AS TotalNew,
        ISNULL(md.TotalQuit, 0) AS TotalQuit
    FROM AllMonths am
    LEFT JOIN MonthlyData md ON am.SchoolId = md.SchoolId AND am.Year = md.Year AND am.Month = md.Month
),
FinalCumulativeTotals AS (
    -- Calculate cumulative totals for each school by month
    SELECT 
        ma.SchoolId,
        ma.Year,
        ma.Month,
        SUM(ma.TotalNew) OVER (PARTITION BY ma.SchoolId ORDER BY ma.Year, ma.Month) -
        SUM(ma.TotalQuit) OVER (PARTITION BY ma.SchoolId ORDER BY ma.Year, ma.Month) AS TotalCount,
        ma.TotalNew,
        ma.TotalQuit,
        ma.TotalNew - ma.TotalQuit AS NetGain
    FROM MonthlyAggregates ma
)
-- Final selection with cumulative count using LAG for previous month total
SELECT 
    SchoolId, 
    Year, 
    Month, 
    LAG(TotalCount, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolId ORDER BY Year, Month) AS TotalCount,
    TotalNew,
    TotalQuit,
    NetGain
FROM FinalCumulativeTotals
ORDER BY SchoolId, Year, Month;

Replace [YourTableName] with the name of your original table.
Fiddle
Explanation:

DateRanges CTE: Establishes dynamic start and end dates for each school based on its earliest DateEntered and the current month.
MonthlyData CTE: Calculates TotalNew and TotalQuit for each month.
AllMonths CTE: Creates a month sequence using master..spt_values (a table with enough rows for month ranges).
MonthlyAggregates CTE: Fills in TotalNew and TotalQuit for each month in sequence.
FinalCumulativeTotals CTE: Calculates cumulative totals using SUM ... OVER for cumulative values up to each month.

Warning and comments:

Check indexing. I don't know your exact original scheme, but ensure [YourTableName] has indexes on SchoolId, DateEntered, and DateInactive if they don’t already exist. These indexes would improve performance, especially for the DateRanges and MonthlyData calculations.
Consider pre-aggregation: If this query is frequently run, consider pre-aggregating MonthlyData results in a materialized view or indexed view, as these aggregations could be reused, especially if this data changes infrequently.


Updated answer:
code a bit changed (main SQL calculation for TotalCount column) with additional school in sample data
SAMPLE DATA:



ID
SchoolID
DateEntered
Active
DateInactive




1
101
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


2
101
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


3
101
2023-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


4
101
2023-08-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2023-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


5
101
2023-08-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2023-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


6
101
2023-12-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
null


7
101
2023-12-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
null


8
101
2024-05-10 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


9
101
2024-06-22 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


10
101
2024-06-22 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


11
101
2024-08-10 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-09-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


12
101
2024-09-07 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


13
101
2024-09-21 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-10-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


14
101
2024-09-21 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


15
201
2023-11-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


16
201
2023-11-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
1
null


17
201
2024-04-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-07-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


18
201
2024-04-13 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00
0
2024-08-14 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00


19
201
2024-05-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
null


20
201
2024-05-09 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00
1
null



WITH 
    --    Recursive CTE
    --      Generate months per SchoolID 
    mnths ( RN, SchoolID, FromDate, TillDate, Span ) AS
      ( Select    1, t.SchoolID, t.MinDate, t.MaxDate, 
                  DateDiff( Month, t.MinDate, t.MaxDate )
        From      ( Select SchoolID, 
                           Min(DateEntered) as MinDate, 
                           GetDate() as MaxDate 
                    From tbl 
                    Group By SchoolID ) t
       UNION ALL
        Select    RN + 1, SchoolID, DateAdd( Month, 1, FromDate ), TillDate, Span
        From      mnths 
        Where     RN <= Span
      ), 

    -- second CTE 
    -- Left Join your table data to months and define MonthQuit column
    -- Count rows (aggregate by SchoolID, MonthID and MonthQuit)
    grid AS 
      ( SELECT m.SchoolID, m.MonthID, 
               Concat( DatePart(Year, act.DateInactive), 
                       '-', 
                      Format(DatePart(Month, act.DateInactive), '00') 
                    ) as MonthQuit, 
               Count(Active) as Active
        FROM   ( Select SchoolID, RN, 
                        Concat( DatePart(Year, FromDate), 
                                '-', 
                                Format(DatePart(Month, FromDate), '00') 
                              ) as MonthID
                 From   mnths
               ) m  
        LEFT JOIN tbl act ON( Coalesce( Concat( DatePart(Year, act.DateEntered), 
                                                '-', 
                                                Format(DatePart(Month, act.DateEntered), '00') 
                                              ), m.MonthID 
                                      ) = m.MonthID AND 
                              Coalesce(act.SchoolID, m.SchoolID ) = m.SchoolID
                           )
      GROUP BY m.SchoolID, m.MonthID, 
               Concat( DatePart(Year, act.DateInactive), 
                       '-', 
                      Format(DatePart(Month, act.DateInactive), '00') 
                    )
    )

--
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT x.SchoolID, x.MonthID, 
       Coalesce(Sum(x.TotalNew - x.TotalQuit) 
             Over(Partition By x.SchoolID 
                  Order By x.MonthID 
                  Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding), 0) as TotalCount,
     x.TotalNew, x.TotalQuit, x.NetGain
FROM ( Select    g.SchoolID, g.MonthID,
                 Coalesce( Sum(g.TotalNew) Over( Partition By g.SchoolID Order By g.MonthID
                                Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding ), 0 ) 
              - 
                 Case When Row_Number() Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID 
                                          Order By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) = 1 
                      Then 
                          Coalesce( Sum(g.Inactive) Over( Partition By g.SchoolID Order By g.MonthID
                                Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And 1 Preceding ), 0 ) 
                 End as TotalCount, 
              --
              Case When Row_Number() Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID 
                                          Order By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) = 1 
                   Then
                        Sum(g.TotalNew) Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) 
              End as TotalNew,
             --
              Case When Row_Number() Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID 
                                          Order By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) = 1 
                   Then
                       Max(g.Inactive) Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) 
              End as TotalQuit, 
             --
              Case When Row_Number() Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID 
                                          Order By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) = 1 
                   Then
                       Sum(g.TotalNew) Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID) 
                    - 
                       Max(g.Inactive) Over(Partition By g.SchoolID, g.MonthID)  
              End as NetGain
      From  ( SELECT   g.*, Coalesce(g2.Active, 0) as Inactive 
              FROM    ( Select   SchoolID, MonthID, MonthQuit,   
                                 Active as TotalNew,
                                 Case When MonthQuit != '-' Then Active Else 0 End as TotalQuit,
                                 Active - Case When MonthQuit != '-' Then Active Else 0 End as NetGain
                        From     grid  
                      ) g
             LEFT JOIN grid g2 ON( g2.SchoolID = g.SchoolID And g2.MonthQuit = g.MonthID )
          ) g
    ) x
WHERE     x.TotalCount Is Not Null
ORDER BY  x.SchoolID, x.MonthID

R e s u l t :



SchoolID
MonthID
TotalCount
TotalNew
TotalQuit
NetGain




101
2023-07
0
3
0
3


101
2023-08
3
2
0
2


101
2023-09
5
0
0
0


101
2023-10
5
0
2
-2


101
2023-11
3
0
0
0


101
2023-12
3
2
0
2


101
2024-01
5
0
0
0


101
2024-02
5
0
0
0


101
2024-03
5
0
0
0


101
2024-04
5
0
0
0


101
2024-05
5
1
0
1


101
2024-06
6
2
0
2


101
2024-07
8
0
0
0


101
2024-08
8
1
0
1


101
2024-09
9
3
1
2


101
2024-10
11
0
2
-2


101
2024-11
9
0
0
0


201
2023-11
0
2
0
2


201
2023-12
2
0
0
0


201
2024-01
2
0
0
0


201
2024-02
2
0
0
0


201
2024-03
2
0
0
0


201
2024-04
2
2
0
2


201
2024-05
4
2
0
2


201
2024-06
6
0
0
0


201
2024-07
6
0
1
-1


201
2024-08
5
0
1
-1


201
2024-09
4
0
0
0


201
2024-10
4
0
0
0


201
2024-11
4
0
0
0



fiddle

You can achieve your desired results as follows:

Truncate all dates to the just the year-month for use in all later operations.
For each student, generate two rows - one for the start (new) date and one for the end (quit) date with start/end (new/quit) flags for each.
Group by school and year/month and sum up the start and end events as well as the net gain (starts - ends).
Generate a school + month calendar data for each school for the range of months for which data is available.
Join the calendar data with the statistics data.
Select the final results. The year-month date is only now split into separate year and month columns. The total attendance is calculated as the running sum of the net-gain column.

WITH SchoolMonthlyStats AS (
    SELECT
        S.SchoolId,
        YM.YearMonth,
        SUM(V.New) AS TotalNew,
        SUM(V.Quit) AS TotalQuit,
        SUM(V.New) - SUM(V.Quit) AS NetGain
    FROM Students S
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (S.DateEntered, 1, 0),  -- New
            (S.DateInactive, 0, 1)  -- Quit
    ) V(Date, New, Quit)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATETRUNC(month, DATE) AS YearMonth) YM
    --WHERE V.Date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY S.SchoolId, YM.YearMonth
),
SchoolMonthCalendar AS (
    SELECT SE.SchoolId, DATEADD(month, S.value, SE.MonthStart) AS YearMonth
    FROM (
        SELECT
            SchoolId,
            MIN(YearMonth) AS MonthStart,
            DATETRUNC(month, GETDATE()) AS MonthEnd
        FROM SchoolMonthlyStats
        GROUP BY SchoolId
    ) SE
    CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(month, SE.MonthStart, SE.MonthENd)) S
)
SELECT
    SMC.SchoolId,
    YEAR(SMC.YearMonth) AS Year,
    MONTH(SMC.YearMonth) AS Month,
    SUM(SMS.NetGain) OVER(PARTITION BY SMC.SchoolId ORDER BY SMC.YearMonth)
        - ISNULL(SMS.NetGain, 0) AS PriorCount,
    ISNULL(SMS.TotalNew, 0) AS TotalNew,
    ISNULL(SMS.TotalQuit, 0) AS TotalQuit,
    ISNULL(SMS.NetGain, 0) AS NetGain,
    SUM(SMS.NetGain) OVER(PARTITION BY SMC.SchoolId ORDER BY SMC.YearMonth) AS NewCount
FROM SchoolMonthCalendar SMC
LEFT JOIN SchoolMonthlyStats SMS
    ON SMS.SchoolId = SMC.SchoolId
    AND SMS.YearMonth = SMC.YearMonth
ORDER BY SMC.SchoolId, SMC.YearMonth

The 'Total Count` column in your desired results actually reflected the prior attendance from the previous month. The above calculates both the prior and current attendance.
The above SQL uses both the DATETRUNC() and GENERATE_SERIES() functions available in SQL Serve 2022 and later. For earlier SQL Server versions, alternate techniques may be used - a DATEDIFF/DATEADD hack to truncate the date, and a recursive CTE to generate the range of dates for the calendar.
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATE), 0) AS YearMonth) YM

SchoolMonthCalendar AS (
    SELECT
        SchoolId,
        MIN(YearMonth) AS YearMonth,
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS YearMonthEnd
    FROM SchoolMonthlyStats
    GROUP BY SchoolId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SchoolId, DATEADD(month, 1, YearMonth), YearMonthEnd
    FROM SchoolMonthCalendar
    WHERE YearMonth < YearMonthEnd
)

Results:



SchoolId
Year
Month
PriorCount
TotalNew
TotalQuit
NetGain
NewCount




3fa85f64-...
2023
7
0
3
0
3
3


3fa85f64-...
2023
8
3
2
0
2
5


3fa85f64-...
2023
9
5
0
0
0
5


3fa85f64-...
2023
10
5
0
2
-2
3


3fa85f64-...
2023
11
3
0
0
0
3


3fa85f64-...
2023
12
3
2
0
2
5


3fa85f64-...
2024
1
5
0
0
0
5


3fa85f64-...
2024
2
5
0
0
0
5


3fa85f64-...
2024
3
5
0
0
0
5


3fa85f64-...
2024
4
5
0
0
0
5


3fa85f64-...
2024
5
5
1
0
1
6


3fa85f64-...
2024
6
6
2
0
2
8


3fa85f64-...
2024
7
8
0
0
0
8


3fa85f64-...
2024
8
8
1
0
1
9


3fa85f64-...
2024
9
9
3
1
2
11


3fa85f64-...
2024
10
11
0
2
-2
9


3fa85f64-...
2024
11
9
0
0
0
9



Note that the 2024-08 NetGain shows a 1 instead of 0 that was listed in the desired results. I believe this to be correct.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both the SQL Server 2022 and prior version queries.
